# ¿Cómo lograr que funcione un DropDownList usando MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

En el código del modelo tengo errores en `IEnumerable` y en `SelectListItem`.

En mensaje de error dice:

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

¿Cuál es la causa de esos errores y su solución?

---

Este es mi código:

```
public CommPortSettingsModel()
{     
    public string SelectedComm { get; set; }}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Comm
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> GenericList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "4" });

            return GenericList;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hola,

Como estas implementando el dropdownlist en la vista? puedes poner el código de la vista?

Comment: Ya arregle el error en las llaves y eso no es.

Comment: La viste no la puedo colocar completa aqui por que me paso en los caracteres, asi tengo implementado el dropdownlist : @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedComm, Model.Comm, new { id = "selectedComm", @class = "form-control" })

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en como esta escrito el codigo, suponiendo que `CommPortSettingsModel` es tu clase

Debería ser

```
public class CommPortSettingsModel
{
    public int SelectedComm { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Comm
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> GenericList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3" });
            GenericList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "4" });

            return GenericList;
        }
    } 
}
```

Observa que el tipo de dato de `SelectedComm` cambia a `int`

Luego en la vista te debería de quedar así:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedComm, new SelectList(Model.Comm, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "selectedComm", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Ya lo arregle así y sigue el error.

Comment: @Wfgo, si no has encontrado la solución, **actualiza tu pregunta**.

Answer (score 1):

A tu código le sobra una llave en la parte de:

```
....code
 public string SelectedComm { get; set; } %}%
........code
```

Independientemente de eso la Respuesta de WFGo es correcta 
y aquí el ejemplo de lo que seria la vista

```
@model  Ruta.Modelo.CommPortSettingsModel
@{
}
<div class="row">
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedComm, Model.Comm, new { id = "selectedComm", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Te recomiendo verifiques la estructura .
[image: Ejemplo]